# Printing correct list index with resulting list element

Tags: r

Just for fun, I wrote a short function that prints the next R `fortune` every 8 seconds.

```
myFortuneFn <- function() {
    require(fortunes)
    l <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(read.fortunes())), fortune)
    print(l[1])
    for(i in seq_along(l)[-1]){
        Sys.sleep(8)
        print(l[i])
    }
}
```

The function prints the correct fortune, but I'd like the list index to be kept in order and print the correct index of the current fortune.  Meaning that in the following, the second result (which came 8 seconds after the first), should have `[[2]]` as its index, not `[[1]]`.  This should be sequential to the end of `l`

```
> myFortuneFn()
# [[1]]
# 
# Okay, let's stand up and be counted: who has been writing diamond graph code? Mine's 60 lines.
#    -- Barry Rowlingson (in a discussion about the patent for diamond graphs)
#       R-help (August 2003)
#
#
# [[1]] ## <- this should read [[2]], and so on all the way to [[360]]
#
# Bug, undocumented behaviour, feature? I don't know. It all seems to work in 1.6.0, so everyone should downgrade
# now... :)
#    -- Barry Rowlingson
#       R-help (July 2003)
```

**How can I fix the printing so the list indices are printed in sequential order as the fortunes are printed?** I've tried `print(c(i, l[[i]]))` in place of the above `print` call, but that changes the output format.

Comment: `l[i]` is a list with a single element. You could utilise `l[[i]]` which is of class `fortune` and has `attr(l[[i]], "row.names")`. Currently `l[[i]]` is printed using `getAnywhere(print.fortune)`

Comment: So you could redefine `print.fortune <- function(x){cat(paste0('[[',attr(x, "row.names"),']]'))}` etc to suit your purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `print.fortune` to print which fortune number is associated with the fortune as given by the `row.names` attribute:

```
require(fortunes)
print.fortune <- function(x){
  cat(paste0('[[',attr(x, "row.names"),']]'))
  cat('\n')
  fortunes:::print.fortune(x)
}
myFortuneFn <- function() {
  l <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(read.fortunes())), fortune)
  for(i in seq_along(l)){
    print(l[[i]])
    Sys.sleep(8)
  }
}


> myFortuneFn()
[[1]]

Okay, let's stand up and be counted: who has been writing diamond graph code? Mine's 60
lines.
   -- Barry Rowlingson (in a discussion about the patent for diamond graphs)
      R-help (August 2003)

[[2]]

Bug, undocumented behaviour, feature? I don't know. It all seems to work in 1.6.0, so
everyone should downgrade now... :)
   -- Barry Rowlingson
      R-help (July 2003)
```

When you are done with the repurposed function you can of course `rm(print.fortune)` to return the default behaviour.